# Asset pipeline broken after pushing to heroku - rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I don't know what happened differently this time - my local env is running great. And my heroku app was running great. I pushed some code, and now it seems as if the asset pipline broke in my heroku app?

/assets/all.css and /assets/application.js both product "not found" errors now.

Any ideas what could have caused this or how I might be able to fix it?

To be clear - my app was working great yesterday. I didnt change the config in regards to the asset pipeline.

Comment: Did you push to the bamboo or the cedar stack?

Comment: Calling `heroku stack`on the command line.

Comment: Any option for migrating to the cedar stack? The cedar stack is required for the asset pipeline to work: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

Comment: Is that new? this was working yesterday...

Comment: Did you change any asset since yesterday? Maybe some stylesheet or an image? Then you have to run `rake assets:precompile` before pushing to heroku.

Comment: when I ran it - there was a lot to commit - but the push didnt change anything

Comment: @ream88 is probobaly right. And make sure that your assets are in the git repo.

Comment: @ream88 Running `git push heroku master` actually executes `rake assets:precompile` among all the other things. I have all my assets committed and pushed to Github, and it runs perfectly locally, but when pushed to Heroku, the CSS and JS references are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference this was apparently a hardware failure for the day at heroku which they notified me of the following day, via email.

Answer (score 1):

As ream88 said, you need the cedar stack to use Asset Pipeline. You need to create a new heroku project with --stack cedar option and **modify your gemfile a bit**.

I have a [blog post](http://blog.bloomingame.com/?p=40) on the subject. You can skip the compass/bootstrap stuff if you don't need it.

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with anything if it was working yesterday... I didn't edit the configuration regarding the asset pipeline, so how could anything have changed that?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I'm surprised your app worked at all. When I started using 3.1, I had spent half a day trying to make it work with the bamboo stack before I finally gave up and migrated to the cedar.

Comment: But did you modify **any asset** file? Because if you did so, its normally that **none** of the assets is found in production mode. Rails adds a digest at the end of the filename, and some assets depend on other. Worst case is that changing one single file results in changing **all** assets filenames.

Comment: Yes - I had definitely modified some CSS and JS files. None of which are now found. So if all of the asset names changed, wouldn't   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> still work?

Comment: Not without compiling the assets again. This is the advantage of the cedar stack, because it will do this task for you after each deployment. And of course you don't need to commit the assets in `public/assets`.